# Insert Value in every nth column in active row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a button that will insert a value in every n'th column in the active row.

To be more specific i want the number "1" to be inserted on every tuesday in this example by the specific employee that i have selected. Later on i want a button for each workday, that'll do the same.

I tried piecing something together by myself, but so far i'm not having any luck. This is what i got so far:

```
Sub EveryTuesday()

Dim i As Long

For i = 5 To Range("M1").Column Step 5
        
    If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value <> "" Then
    
        Sheet1.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Columns(i)).Value = "1"
    
    End If
    
Next
```

End Sub

The result in this very simplified worksheet should be something like this after i selected "Joe" and hit the button named "every tuesday":

[image]

I'm still a newbie in the VBA-world, but i'm trying. I hope you can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Sheet1.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, i).Value = "1"`

Comment: Thank you!!!! 

I cant believe i didnt try that.... It's often the simplest solutions right in front of you, that you never notice.